# check if row has a particular value (perl,mysql)

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm trying to identify if a row has the value '1' anywhere in it (AKA any column). Is there an easy way to do this without searching every column with `fetchrow_array`? I've included a small table I've been working with as an example.

```
mysql> select * from Case_Tracking;
+--------------------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
| accession_number   | cyp2d6  | cyp2c19 | factorII | factorV | apoe     | vkorc1_cyp2c9 |
+--------------------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
| AIB14-1116-0000453 | Luminex | Luminex | Hologic  |       1 | ABI 7500 | Genmark       |
| AIB14-1123-0000074 | NULL    | Luminex | Hologic  | Hologic | ABI 7500 | Genmark       |
+--------------------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to search every column using SQL (`WHERE accession_number = '1' OR cyp2d6 = '1' OR ...`) since you'd only need to fetch matching results.

Comment: Thanks, I thought maybe I was missing some sort of magical function, but it seems I have to  look at each column.